# external monitor not detected after login

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor, intel-graphics, deepin

I am using `deepin 15.14.1` with dual monitor setup & dual graphic card. My primary monitor is connected to Nvidia GT610 (VGA) and external monitor is connected to integrated graphics (Intel HD 4600)(VGA). On booting deepin both monitor shows deepin logo once i reach login screen, external monitors shows nothing even after login

> Here's xrandr output

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-2 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

> Driver Manager

[image]

**UPDATE**

I changed nvidia driver from open-source nvidia official driver and now after login external monitor shows black screen with a dash cursor.  I am still not able to detect my external monitor. However xrandr output changed a bit, Now its showing 2 DVI ports

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Also i just noticed during boot my monitor shows `bbswitch: no suitable dsm call found`

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, one monitor is blank , but shows both displays in Display manager.

As a work around I installed i3 window manager and then both displays are coming up

Comment: I am new to linux. It looks something to with stacking windows. Can you provide me instruction to install how to get my both displays working?